# Rules module not enabling via Drush in drupal 7

Tags: 7, rules, drush

this may be a simple one however while downloading Rules through drush
 and getting the following error.

```
root@li:/var/www/drupal7/sites/default# drush en rules*

No release history was found for the requested project (i18n_string).[warning]
Module rules_i18n cannot be enabled because it depends on the        [error]
following modules which could not be found: i18n_string
```

I also tried doing drush dl il8n_rules but to no use.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need the i18n module to install rules_i18n

```
drush dl i18n
drush en i18n_string
drush en rules*
```

Alternatively, enable the rules submodules individually, excluding rules_i18n